# UITableViewCell only updates to correct height when scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a dynamic UITableViewCells, some of them at loading the cells are correct height but there are some that only update to correct layout when tableview scrolling up and down.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
    self.heightAtIndexPath = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```

Here is my tableView delegates:

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object {


    cell.imageView.file = (PFFile *)object[@"image"];
            [cell.imageView loadInBackground:^(UIImage * _Nullable image, NSError * _Nullable error) {

                cell.imageHeightConstraint.constant = image.size.height / image.size.width * cell.cardView.frame.size.width;
                [cell.imageView updateConstraints];


            }];

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSNumber *height = [self.heightAtIndexPath objectForKey:indexPath];
    if(height) {
        return height.floatValue;
    } else {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
    }
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSNumber *height = @(cell.frame.size.height);
    [self.heightAtIndexPath setObject:height forKey:indexPath];
}
```

Comment: Are the heights all approximately (or exactly the same) height?

Comment: @jjatie I suppose so, i mean some images are smaller in height than others yes.

Comment: In that case try commenting out the estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath method (The entire method, not just the implementation). I had the same issue before, and found this answer in WWDC 2014 Mysteries of Auto Layout

Comment: Okay thanks, ill try it out.

Comment: Also make sure you have not set a specific row height in Interface Builder

Comment: @jjatie also when it does update for example from a big cell height to a smaller cell height, is there a way to make the transition smooth instead of glitchy?

Comment: how do you not specify a row height?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113716/discussion-between-jjatie-and-farhan).

Answer (score 1):

From this WWDC lecture (approximate 25 minutes in) [Mysteries of Auto Layout](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-218/?time=1450), avoid using estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath, and make sure Auto Layout constraints are properly implemented. It is also generally a good idea to not set a row height in Interface Builder if using dynamic cell heights.

Answer (score 1):

you are missing the `estimatedRowHeight`

```
func configureTableView() {
  tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
  tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 160.0
}
```

Check out 
[Dynamic Table View Cell Height](https://www.raywenderlich.com/87975/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-ios-8-swift)

Comment: does estimatedRowHeight supposed to change the height visually untill its calculated?

Comment: In apple's documentation both must be set.
[Working with Self-Sizing Table View Cells](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithSelf-SizingTableViewCells.html)
"To enable self-sizing table view cells, you must set the table view’s rowHeight property to UITableViewAutomaticDimension. You must also assign a value to the estimatedRowHeight property. As soon as both of these properties are set, the system uses Auto Layout to calculate the row’s actual height."

Answer (score 0):

Set estimated row height in `viewDidload` also something like,

```
   self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100; //estimated value
```

and don't implement `estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath` this method and `reload tableview in viewDidappear` or `viewWillAppear`.

Hope this will help :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your cell looks like in the code, but from the issue you're having it could be if you don't initialises the `UITableViewCell` with a reuseIdentifier: `UITableViewCell(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: "myCell")`